# Activiti + Hibernate: common transaction manager

Tags: hibernate, activiti

I try to use common transaction manager for Activiti & Hibernate. They have common DB. I try to save the same entity firstly with help of Hibernate and then with help of Activiti:

```
Session session = ((SessionFactory) applicationContext.getBean("sessionFactory")).openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

session.save(client);
execution.setVariable("client", client);

session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

**Problem:**

I don't see any record for client-entity in activiti's ACT_RU_VARIABLE table.

**Question:**

How to ensure that Activiti use the same transaction as Hibernate?

**ADDITION:**

*applicationContext.xml*

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
    <!-- Configuration -->  
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties" />

    <!-- Annotation based configuration -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="name.krestjaninoff" /> 


    <!-- Data -->
     <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/activiti-transaction-demo"/>
        <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
    </bean>
    <!--
        Activiti 
    -->
    <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
        <property name="databaseType" value="postgres" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <!--<property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="create" />-->
        <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />
        <property name="history" value="audit" />
        <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="false" />
        <property name="deploymentResources" value="classpath*:/process/*.bpmn20.xml" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="processEngine" class="org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="processEngineConfiguration" ref="processEngineConfiguration" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="repositoryService" factory-bean="processEngine"
        factory-method="getRepositoryService" />
    <bean id="runtimeService" factory-bean="processEngine"
        factory-method="getRuntimeService" />
    <bean id="taskService" factory-bean="processEngine"
        factory-method="getTaskService" />
    <bean id="historyService" factory-bean="processEngine"
        factory-method="getHistoryService" />
    <bean id="managementService" factory-bean="processEngine"
        factory-method="getManagementService" />

    <!--
       Hibernate
    -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>name.krestjaninoff.activiti.hello.db</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect</prop>
                <!--<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>-->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" scope="singleton">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: according to Activiti documentation http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#N12127 to add entity as a process variable you need to configure entities with JPA annotations and processEngine must have a reference to an EntityManagerFactory. May be this is the reason why entity doesn't get inserted into ACT_RU_VARIABLE table.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: process-variables are flushed to DB only when process reaches a wait stait, finished or lauch asynchronous task. And ACT_RU_VARIABLE table is cleaned after process finished. So, to see any records in ACT_RU_VARIABLE table you need to check it during UserTask.